# Where can I find the hashing algorithm in source code?

Tags: android, encryption, java, hash-functions

When I submit login credentials in an Android Application it POSTs an encrypted string to an API endpoint.

For example, if I enter the following email & pass :

"abc@abbc.com:abc"

it POSTs the following Encrypted Data:

```
uuid=81d036bfca2258ea_nofq2ipit&model=SM-G977N&platform=Android&version=5.1.1&complie=android&token=%7B%22ct%22%3A%22ryYURhKTo02TMPyxP2vPG93FFw%2FkQ%2FP%2B129znAYCKC4%3D%22%2C%22iv%22%3A%221b99dad6887136408d84fbce42ea31f1%22%2C%22s%22%3A%22033a413ac951a2d0%22%7D&key=0.8615443813135553
```

How do I find the encryption algorithm in the source code of the APK?

In which file can I find about this encryption?

Dex2Zip: https://www.mediafire.com/file/gzn73270ujnyvmc/Dex.zip/file

APK: https://www.mediafire.com/file/118lcjhxohcczt0/BJ.apk/file

Comment: I would start using Jadx and open the APK file. Then use Jadx search feature try to find out where the URL and especially the URL encoded part `token` is generated and how. If it is really a digest and the app uses digest provided by Android search for `Digest.getInstance(`